# Dynamic node php variable sites

Tags: php, html, variables, dynamic

I am new here, so forgive me for being new.  I am working on a little site.  I am setting up a database for some inventory.  I have the below code working, which will create a working link to a html.

```
      foreach($fetchData as $data){
          $linkid = $data['lid']??'';
    $linkaddress="editradio.php?radioID=$linkid"; ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $data['lid']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['radio_typ']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['user']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['badge']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['entity']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['department']??''; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $data['radio_serial']??''; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $data['setup_date']??''; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $data['author']??''; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo "<a href='$linkaddress'>Edit</a>"; ?></td>
       <td></td>
```

I am wondering how I can create a template page which, when someone goes to that link, it will call up the variable in the SQL, and then fill out the page.

I'd prefer to not use a template engine or anything more complicated.  Just a simple php template.

Comment: If you don't want to use a template framework, you have to write out the code that does the SQL query and displays the editing form. There's no shortcut.

Comment: I don't mind writing the code, but I guess I am a little lost on how to actually take the extension of the url (editradio.php?radioID=XXXX) and detect what the XXXX is in the php file.  I would then just look up XXXX thru SQL when I had that variable from within the PHP file.   I imagine that can be done without a bunch of extra java script and such?  Or am I wrong?

Comment: `$_GET['radioID']` will contain `XXXX`. Sounds like you need to read a tutorial on how PHP gets parameters from forms and links.

Comment: Thank you!  I probably do, yes.   I am used to using templates and such.  But for this project, it is for a little work thing, and I didn't want to deal with licensing.  Just been swamped with other stuff - staff shortages and such.   bleh.   

But thanks a ton!  That should get me what I need to complete things.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on processing form input and doing SQL queries in PHP.